# Joining two tables in sql based on greater than condition

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this requirement where I have two tables,

**Employee Table :**

| Employee | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| David | 1200 |
| Felix | 2200 |

**Tax** :

| Lower Salary Range | Higher Salary Range | TaxRate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 | .3 |
| 2001 | 3000 | .4 |

Based on the Salary in employee Table, Tax needs to be calculated by fetching the tax rate from Tax table.

I need to write the query so that both the tables can be joined together. However, there is no direct matching columns between the two tables. It can only be joined using the condition, `Employee.Salary > Tax.LowerSalaryRange and Employee.Salary < Tax.HigherSalaryRange`.

Query Looks like this and this gives me the correct results as well

```
select Salary*Rate
from Employee E
join Tax T
  on E.Salary >= T.LowerSalaryRange and E.Salary <  T.HigherSalaryRange
```

Would like to check if this the correct way to write the query.

Edit : I would like to understand if I can use greater than and less than signs while joining two tables.

Comment: I suppose you want `<=` and `>=`. Or `on Salary between LowerSalaryRange and HigherSalaryRange`.

Comment: You should search for alias and why/how to use them

Comment: *I would like to understand if I can use greater than and less than signs while joining two tables.* You may use ANY expression which produces the result which can be treated as boolean.. even a subquery: `.. FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (SELECT .. FROM t3 WHERE ..) ..`.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Should work.

It does look a bit dangerous though because it means you need to be very cautious on how your Tax data table is filled so that there are no intersection nor missing gaps in your salary ranges.

I don't know if you expect salary to always be an integer (which would be weird) but in your case, you do have a gap between 2000 and 2001.

Also if you have huge data, do not forget to add an index your `Employee.Salary` column.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Just a bit curious, if there is an alternated way to approach this problem.

Comment: Well. The way I would do it would be within the code, not the database, with exception raised if the salary is out of bounds.